# How can I filter and display JSON data based on user input?

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON data stored in a file:

```
[  
   {  
      "AA+A":0.3021,
      "A+AA":0.3021,
      "AAAU+AA":0.0677,
      "AA+AAAU":0.0677,
      "AABA+AAAU":0.092,
      "AAAU+AABA":0.092,
      "AAC+AABA":0.1713,
      "AABA+AAC":0.1713,
      "ULE+DXB":-0.0614,
      "DXB+ULE":-0.0614,
      "ULE+FLKR":0.308,
      "FLKR+ULE":0.308,
      "BNTCW+BAPR": "NaN"
   }
]
```

and the following form :

```
 Stock1: -------
 Stock1: -------
      Submit
```

How can I filter the JSON file based on the user input values(Stock1-value and Stock2-value) and display the data in a div for example and if the data is not available, it should say - 'not available':

Ex:

```
Stock1: AA
Stock1: A
Submit and display : 0.3021
```

or

```
Stock1: A
Stock1: AA
Submit and display : 0.3021
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check property exist or not using [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and then show message based on that.

```js
var data = [{"AA+A":0.3021,"A+AA":0.3021,"AAAU+AA":0.0677,"AA+AAAU":0.0677,"AABA+AAAU":0.092,"AAAU+AABA":0.092,"AAC+AABA":0.1713,"AABA+AAC":0.1713,"ULE+DXB":-0.0614,"DXB+ULE":-0.0614,"ULE+FLKR":0.308,"FLKR+ULE":0.308,"BNTCW+BAPR":"NaN"}];

// cache element to reuse
let $res = $('#res');
// cache elements and bind input event handlers
let $stks = $('#stock1,#stock2').on('input', function() {
  // iterate over elements to get value and then generate key
  let key = $stks.map(function() {
  // get value
    return this.value.trim();
  })
  // get result as an array and then join with + symbol
  .get().join('+');
  // show result baked on key
  $res.text(key in data[0] ? data[0][key] : 'Not found')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="stock1"><input id="stock2">
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: and how can I add this functionality via the submit button also: when pressing submit to display the data , and if no data to display a message ?

Comment: @Junior.junioryou have to do the same operation within event handler callback function

Comment: like this? :
`<input type="submit" class="button" id="submitDemo"/>`



`$('#submitDemo').on('click',function(){
    //your code here
});`

Comment: But it does not display the data from the div when submitting 
`<div id="res"></div>`

Comment: hm, still not working, on submit we have the function to manipulate the json filter, but it is not linked wit the div itself somehow , the div that stores the filtered json data

Comment: @Junior.junior :  move code to xhr success callback

Comment: And how can we prevent the refreshing, because after the data is displayed it is automatically refresh and we lose it. maybe to keep the data displayed until the next submit call

Comment: @Junior.junior : `$('#submitDemo').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); `